# Retrieve members from an Azure AD group including service principals

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cli, azure-service-principal

I have an Azure AD group containing a User, a Group and a service principal. I want to retrieve them with the Azure CLI.

When trying this:

```
az ad group member list --group <my_group_id>
```

Only the User and Group details are being retrieved.
I double check for the service principal being there with:

```
az ad group member check --group <my_group_id> --member-id <service_pricipal_id>
```

and it returns to true.

How can I retrieve the service principal that is part of the group as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results***

I created one Azure AD group and added one **`user, group and service principal`** as members like below:

[image]

I executed the same query in CLI and got response including service principal too like below:

```
az ad group member list --group <my_group_id>
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Alternatively**, you can run query like below and can retrieve members with their **`displayName`** and **`objectType`** by selecting specific properties:

```
az ad group member list --group <my_group_id> --only-show-errors --query "[].{displayName:displayName,ObjectType:objectType}" -o table
```

**Response:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Please note that, response varies based on the version of CLI we are using.

My CLI version is as below: `az version`

[image]

If you are using an upgraded/different version, you won't get service principals in the response as mentioned in this [**MS Doc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

> Currently service principals are not listed as group members due to
> staged roll-out of service principals on Graph V1.0 endpoint.

***I tried to list the group members of same group using **[MS Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)** by running query like below:***

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<my_group_id>/members
```

**Response:**

[image]

I got only user and group in the response **without service principal**.

You can check the below **GitHub** issue to know more in detail:

[`az ad group member list` does not list service principals. Issue #22664 -GitHub by Kevin Haring](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/22664)

Comment: This is strange. I've tried with a new group adding only a person and a service principal. It still only retrieves the person only. Could this be related? https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/16698

Comment: Please check the updated answer...

Comment: using `az rest` on the graph API worked